# DropDown menu with QtQuickControls2 on Qt application

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

on qt quick controls 2, how can I configure a button Item with a dropdown menu of others buttons. When the user click on this button is triggered onClicked signal and under the button should be open a dropdown menu with other buttons. I have try with ButtonGroup but I don't know if this is the best practice. There is some Controls2 item to be use? Thanks in advice

Best Regards
Daniele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`Menu`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html)  from QtQuick.Controls 2.0 that can do what you want.

Example taken from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html#details) :

[image: Popup button menu]

```
Button {
    id: fileButton
    text: "File"
    onClicked: menu.open()

    Menu {
        id: menu
        y: fileButton.height

        MenuItem {
            text: "New..."
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Open..."
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Save"
        }
    }
}
```